# Python: Calculating a sum for each loop

Tags: python, loops, nested, sum

How do I find a sum of a list of numbers that are in a nested loop?

```
    s=0
    people=eval(input())
    for i in range(people):
        firstn=input()
        lastn=input()
        numbers=(eval(input()))

        print(firstn, lastn, numbers)
        for b in range(numbers):

        numbers=eval(input())
        s+=numbers

        print(b)
```

The input is as followed:

```
    5 #nubmer of people I need to calculate
    Jane #firstname
    Doe #lastname
    4 #number of floats for each person, pretty sure this is for the second loop
    38.4 #these are the floats that i need to calculate for each person to find their sum
    29.3
    33.3
    109.74
    William #loop should reset here as this is the next person's first name
    Jones
    2
    88.8
    99.9
    firstname
    lastname
    number of floats
    float1
    float2...
```

I need to find how to calculate the sum of the indefinite numbers per loop, the problem i'm having right now is that the loop is not resetting each value for each person and i'm getting a sum total.

Comment: why `eval`? use `int()` or `float()`.

Comment: TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: try something like : `numbers=float(input())` or `numbers=int(input())`.

Comment: @James What if the user gives `__import__('os').system("echo 'Random code execution'")` as input? **Never** use `eval`. If you want to evaluate literals then go with `ast.literal_eval`, which is safe.

Comment: Extremely good point.  All developers need to print this comic out and post it in their office: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = []
people = int(raw_input())
for i in range(people):
    firstn = raw_input()
    lastn = raw_input()
    numbers = int(raw_input())

    print(firstn, lastn, numbers)
    temp = 0
    for b in range(numbers):
        numbers = float(raw_input())
        temp += numbers
    s.append(temp)
print(s)
```

I think if you want to record all of the results of the inner loop and no print you need a list. I have tested your given input and it is OK with Python2.7.

Comment: I have edited my answer and tested the code. I works for your input with Python2.7. You may have a try. @James

Comment: It's python 3, says that raw_input is not defined

Comment: Just replace all the `raw_input()` with `input()` and it's OK.@James

Comment: It does work, thank you so much, is there any way I can get each total next to each person's name, otherwise for them to be printed in the first loop?

Comment: The temp is your total for each. You can do anything you want on it. But I think you may want to use them so I store it rather than print it. If you like, just print them, replace `s.append(temp)` with `print(temp)`.@James

Comment: Well i actually need them on the same print line for the first loop, it does print correctly but it prints on a separate line none the less, is there anyway to get the sum on the same line as print(firstn,lastn,numbers)?

Comment: Remove your `print(firstn, lastn, numbers)`, and then replace `s.append(temp)` with `print(firstn, lastn, numbers, temp)`.@James

Answer (score 1):

This is the  easiest solution that I can think of :

```
nop=int(input())
for _ in range(nop):
    fname,lname=input(),input()
    n=int(input())
    summ=sum(float(input()) for _ in range(n))
    print("For {0} {1} the sum is {2}".format(fname,lname,summ))
```

**output:**

```
$ python3 foo.py < abc
For Jane Doe the sum is 210.74
For William Jones the sum is 188.7
```

where `abc` contains:

```
2
Jane
Doe
4
38.4
29.3
33.3
109.74
William
Jones
2
88.8
99.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is phrased poorly, but if I understand correctly, this might work.

```
people = int(input('Enter number of people: ')) # eval is generally not a good idea
for i in range(people):
    firstn = input()
    lastn = input()

    numbers= int(input('Enter number: '))

    print(firstn, lastn, numbers)

    print(sum(numbers)) # prints sum of 0,1,2...numbers-1
```

This is assuming you are using Python 3.  For Python 2.7, replace the `input()` with `raw_input()`

Hope this answers your question

Comment: This is my second question, i can't seem to put the inputs as a list as I would like, they're not showing up how I indented them regardless, the indefinite number of inputs are all floats.

Comment: Something like: `input_list = []    while True:    in = float(input('Enter next input (enter nothing to cancel)'))  if not in:  break  else:  input_list.append(in)`

Comment: @James Better provide a sample input/output in the question body.

Comment: I've gotten the result as firstname, lastname, sum of each float inputs not the floats themselves, which i need.